# i am getting error while inserting cte values into the table

Tags: sql-server

```
INSERT INTO CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2 (NCLAIMID, SATTYFILENO, DTLASTPMT, ACTUALPMTDATE, SWORKSTATIONID, DTCHANGEDON, NCHANGEDBY, NAPPLICATIONID)
; WITH LST_CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        NCLAIMID, MAX(DTTRANSACTION) AS ACTUALPMTDATE 
    FROM 
        CLAIMREGISTRY 
    WHERE 
        NTRANLINKID IS NULL
        AND NTRANSACTIONCODEID IN (1,13)
    GROUP BY 
        NCLAIMID
) 

SELECT 
    C.NCLAIMID, C.SATTYFILENO, C.DTLASTPMT,
    L.ACTUALPMTDATE, C.SWORKSTATIONID, C.DTCHANGEDON,
    C.NCHANGEDBY, C.NAPPLICATIONID
FROM 
    CLAIM AS C
JOIN 
    LST_CTE AS L ON L.NCLAIMID = C.NCLAIMID
WHERE 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, C.DTLASTPMT, 112) <> CONVERT(VARCHAR, L.ACTUALPMTDATE, 112)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: put your insert before the SELECT statement but after the cte declaration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring your `cte` first:

```
;with LST_CTE as (
  select NCLAIMID
   , MAX(DTTRANSACTION) as ACTUALPMTDATE
  from CLAIMREGISTRY
  where NTRANLINKID is null and NTRANSACTIONCODEID in (1, 13)
  group by NCLAIMID
 )
insert into CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2 (
 NCLAIMID
 , SATTYFILENO
 , DTLASTPMT
 , ACTUALPMTDATE
 , SWORKSTATIONID
 , DTCHANGEDON
 , NCHANGEDBY
 , NAPPLICATIONID
 )
select C.NCLAIMID
 , C.SATTYFILENO
 , C.DTLASTPMT
 , L.ACTUALPMTDATE
 , c.SWORKSTATIONID
 , c.DTCHANGEDON
 , c.NCHANGEDBY
 , c.NAPPLICATIONID
from CLAIM as C
  inner join LST_CTE as L 
    on L.NCLAIMID = C.NCLAIMID
where CONVERT(varchar(30), C.DTLASTPMT, 112) <> CONVERT(varchar(30), L.ACTUALPMTDATE, 112)
```

Also, if `DTLASTPMT` and `ACTUALPMTDATE` are `date` or `datetime` data types, you do not need to `convert()` them to compare them.

Answer (score 2):

The `with` goes before the `insert` . . . and there is no semicolon in the middle of a statement:

```
WITH LST_CTE AS (
    SELECT NCLAIMID,MAX(DTTRANSACTION) AS ACTUALPMTDATE FROM CLAIMREGISTRY 
    WHERE NTRANLINKID IS NULL
    AND NTRANSACTIONCODEID IN (1,13)
    GROUP BY NCLAIMID
) 
insert into CLEANUP.DBO.TMP_CLAIM_PBI33562_2 (NCLAIMID, SATTYFILENO,DTLASTPMT,ACTUALPMTDATE,SWORKSTATIONID,DTCHANGEDON,NCHANGEDBY,NAPPLICATIONID)
    SELECT C.NCLAIMID, C.SATTYFILENO,C.DTLASTPMT,L.ACTUALPMTDATE,c.SWORKSTATIONID,c.DTCHANGEDON,c.NCHANGEDBY,c.NAPPLICATIONID
    FROM CLAIM C JOIN
         LST_CTE L 
         ON L.NCLAIMID = C.NCLAIMID
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), C.DTLASTPMT, 112) <> CONVERT(VARCHAR(255), L.ACTUALPMTDATE, 112);
```

I also don't like the `WHERE` clause.  If you want to compare just the dates, then compare dates:

```
WHERE CAST(C.DTLASTPMT as DATE) = CAST(L.ACTUALPMTDATE as DATE)
```

Why convert to a string to compare a date?